# Remove image from certain treeview item?

Tags: c++, winapi, treeview

I have a `treeview` with `checkboxes` and it has `imagelist` set with `TreeView_SetImageList()`.

I am trying to remove image from nodes that do not have children. I was successful in removing `checkboxes` from parent nodes, so I thought to try the similar approach:

```
// add an item

TVINSERTSTRUCT tvis = {0};

tvis.item.mask = TVIF_TEXT //  | TVIF_IMAGE;

//   tvis.item.iImage = -1;           // I thought this will work
//   tvis.item.iSelectedImage = -1;   // but it does not work at all

tvis.item.pszText = L"Some text";
tvis.hInsertAfter = TVI_LAST;
tvis.hParent = TVI_ROOT;

htItem = reinterpret_cast<HTREEITEM>( SendMessage( hwndTV, 
    TVM_INSERTITEM, 0, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>( &tvis ) ) );

// remove image

TVITEM tvi;

tvi.hItem = htItem;
tvi.mask = TVIF_IMAGE | TVIF_SELECTEDIMAGE;
tvi.iImage = -1;
tvi.iSelectedImage = -1;

TreeView_SetItem( hwndTV, &tvi );
```

It does not work as expected. At first the image is not shown, but the item text is not next to the `checkbox`:

[image]

If I select another item the image suddenly reappears:

[image]

If I click on the problematic node again I get the same result, as shown in the first picture.

My question is simple:

How do I remove an image from a node?

Thank you.

Best regards.

Comment: I would say that having the item text left-aligned was preferable to having a staggered alignment, since this would make it much harder for the user to scan the tree quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot remove images from individual nodes.  Once you have an image list assigned, the TreeView reserves space for the list's images on all nodes equally, even if individual nodes do not display images from the list.

To do what you are asking, do not assign the image list at all, and then [custom-drawn the nodes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff919569.aspx#list_tree) to make them appear however you want.

Comment: Can tree-view be owner-drawn in pure Winapi? I haven't seen the style `TVS_OWNERDRAW` or similar in MSDN docs. Matbe the only choice I have is custom-draw? Thank you. Best regards.

Comment: Yes, you can [Custom Draw a TreeView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff919569(v=vs.85).aspx#list_tree).